# odroid u3 - wifi issue

Tags: wireless, usb, lubuntu, arm, realtek-wireless

I have an `odroid U3` running `lubuntu 14.04` and cant seem to get wifi working with a `realtek rtl8188EU` usb adapter.
When I run `lsusb` it outputs `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtak Semiconductor Corp.`

I seem to have a similar issue to this person: http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=77&t=11910

But somehow they managed to get it working with this article http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=1674

I am stuck on the process `make all` as I get this error:
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.8.13.30/build M=/rtl8188eu modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.8.13.30/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2`

when i run `ll arch/arm/configs` i get an error:
`ls: cannot access arch/arm/configs: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a driver this way. Connect to internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

reboot and run

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

and reboot.

Comment: thank you, im getting `sudo: dkms: command not found`.

Comment: Install dkms then. `sudo apt-get install dkms`.

Comment: dkms installed!  now im getting `Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.8.13.30 cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.8.13.30 package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
`

Comment: You have a weird kernel version for 14.04.  Why do you use that kernel? It is outdated and headers for it are not available in repositories.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install linux-generic`, reboot and try again.

Comment: followed the instructions but still getting error: `Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.8.13.30 cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.8.13.30 package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29164/discussion-between-t-q-and-pilot6).